# Is it OK to use HashedWheelTimer for long running and periodic tasks?

Tags: timer, scheduled-tasks, netty

Currently I am using the Netty timer for long running tasks (database access) and periodic tasks (simply creating new timeout on execution). But now I am getting unsure if this is alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashedWheelTimer` is using a single thread for executing `TimerTasks`, so any blocking calls or long-running processing in the `TimerTask#run()` method could potentially stall the timer. It is probably a good idea to hand off the database access tasks to a separate `Executor`.